# Vuejs with v-for and v-model with checkboxes fails to clear after uncheck then recheck

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following form

```
<tr v-for="(check, key) in checklistitems ">
  <td>
    <input type="radio" v-model="items_form.yes[key]" :value="check.id" :name="radioname(check)" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" v-model="items_form.no[key]" :value="check.id" :name="radioname(check)" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input v-model="items_form.comment[key]" type="text" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input v-model="items_form.date_expiry[key]" type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

And, I have a computed property which gives the name

```
data: () => ({

  items_form: {
    no: [],
    yes: [],
    comment: []
      .....
  }
})
```

The comment works perfectly but the radio buttons fail.

Such that when I check the `yes` radio for the first time it sets the value correctly, when I check `no` it still checks the value but doesn't clear the previous `yes` value.

What else do I need to add?

Comment: Radio buttons are mutually-exclusive; you're meant to bind the `v-model` of each radio button to the same data property (unless I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving both your radio input different models, that is why it is not working.

In order to be able to 'toggle' or switch one or the other, they should have the same model and only the value should be different as seen in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/13/)

So, use this instead.:

```
<td>
  <input type="radio" v-model="items_form.no[key]" value="yes"/>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="radio" v-model="items_form.no[key]" value="no"/>
</td>
```